# Vuejs select won't select right options

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

When I'm in edit page I expect to get my saved product tags selected by default.

Currently it only selects 1 of them and repeat it as much tags as I have (example)

[image: one]

## Code

`HTML`

```
<el-col :span="22">
    <el-select
        v-model="form.tags"
        multiple
        filterable
        style="width:100%;"
        allow-create
        default-first-option
        placeholder="Choose tags for your product">
        <el-option
            v-for="item in tagss"
            :key="item.id"
            :label="item.name"
            :value="item.name">
        </el-option>
    </el-select>
</el-col>

<el-form-item label="Categories">
    <el-col :span="24">
        <el-cascader
            v-model="form.categories"
            style="width: 100%;"
            :options="cats"
            :props="{
                multiple: true,
                checkStrictly: true,
                value: 'id',
                label: 'name',
            }"
            clearable
            filterable>
        </el-cascader>
    </el-col>
</el-form-item>
```

`Script`

```
data() {
    return {
        cats: [],
        tagss: [],
        form: {
            tags: [],
            categories: [],
            _method: 'PUT',
        },
    }
},
mounted () {
    this.fetchProduct()
    this.getData()
},
methods: {
    getData () {
        axios.get('/api/admin/products', {
            headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token')
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            this.brands = response.data.brands;
            this.cats = response.data.categories;
            this.tagss = response.data.tags;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('error', error);
        });
    },
    fetchProduct() {
        axios
            .get('/api/admin/products/'+this.$route.params.id, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token')
                }
            })
            .then(response => {
                this.form.tags = response.data.data.tags
                this.form.categories = response.data.data.categories
                console.log('all tags from backend: ', this.tagss) // sample data below
                console.log('this product tags from backend: ', response.data.data.tags) // sample data below
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('error', error);
            });
    }
}
```

> here is sample results of my `console.log` in code above

[image: two]

> note: I've mentioned my tags in this question but also shared my categories code as well, as you can see my categories have the same issue.

**Any idea what might be the issue?**

Comment: I never used this component in my life, but I was curious and I gone to check in their docs. I don't find any example of the component used as you do, but instead the option are passed as a prop: 
https://vue-select.org/guide/values.html#tagging

Comment: @Raffobaffo [docs](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/cascader#cascader)

Comment: Yeah, here it use a different component `el-cascader`you are using `el-select`

Comment: My bad i was working on something else :D

Comment: Lol, happens! Good I noticed after you sent me the link !

Comment: anyway, adding props doesn't do anything but damage.

Comment: You updated the answer using el-cascader just in the second iteration, and you didn't explain what it means "damage".

Comment: @Raffobaffo `1` my `tags` using `el-select` and my `categories` using `el-cascader`.  `2` by damage i meant if return more errors that I'm currently getting. `3` just as an idea: what about mapping my product tags into total tags? would that be the solution?

Comment: I don't know. I would stick to the correct element for the job and follow docs. I see you have many callbacks to use to format your data inside el-cascader options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

`Final code`

```
this.form.tags = response.data.data.tags.map(row => row.name);
this.form.categories = response.data.data.categories.map(row => row.id);
```

`Result`

[image: one]